# Node.js: run external process tasks with aync functions or with a queue based worker?

Tags: node.js, web-worker

I have the following function to resize an image and upload to S3 (using 'gm' and 'knox'):

```
var http = require('http');
var https = require('https');
var s3 = require('./s3');
var gm = require('gm');
var fs = require('fs');

module.exports.processImageUrl = function(imageUrl, filename, callback) {
    var client = http;
    if (imageUrl.substr(0, 8) == 'https://') { client = https; }

    client.get(imageUrl, function(res) {
        if (res.statusCode != 200) {
            return callback(new Error('HTTP Response code ' + res.statusCode));
        }

        gm(res)
            .geometry(1024, 768, '>')
            .stream('jpg', function(err, stdout, stderr) {
                if (!err) {
                    var file = fs.createWriteStream(__dirname + '/../tmp/' + filename + '.jpg');

                    stdout.pipe(file);

                    stdout.on('end', function() {
                        fs.stat(__dirname + '/../tmp/' + filename +'.jpg', function(err, stats) {
                            if (!err) {
                                var headers = {
                                    'Content-Length': stats.size
                                    ,     'Content-Type': 'Image/jpeg'
                                    , 'x-amz-acl': 'public-read'
                                };

                                var file = fs.createReadStream(__dirname + '/../tmp/' + filename + '.jpg');

                                s3.putStream(file, '/img/d/' + filename + '.jpg', headers, function(err, res) {
                                    if(err) {
                                        return callback(err);
                                    } else {
                                        fs.unlink(__dirname + '/../tmp/' + filename + '.jpg');
                                        return callback(null, res.client._httpMessage.url);
                                    }
                                });
                            }
                        });
                    });
                } else {
                    callback(err);
                }
            });
    }).on('error', function(err) {
            callback(err);
        });
};
```

potentially if I handle many concurrent requests, many GraphicsMagick processes will be spawned, is it a better practice to implement a queue based worker to process the images and spawn controlled number of processes ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's absolutely better to manage this in a queue. You don't want end users to be able to grind your service to a halt due to number of requests, and DOS attacks become trivial when you're not queueing high CPU operations. I would even consider putting the GraphicsMagick code onto a different server / servers so you can easily scale them independent of the http code.

Comment: are there any good libraries to look at for managing such workers ?